# c++ can't compile a file

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner at c++ and I'm trying to write a program to find greatest common factor. In main i have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "longgcd.cpp"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  long gcd(long m, long n);
  long m,n,g;
  m=atol(argv[1]);
  n=atol(argv[2]);
  g=gcd(m,n);
  std::cout<<"gcd("<<m<<","<<n<<")="<<g<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and then i put the subfunction into another file called longgcd.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
long gcd( long m, long n){
  long r;
  while(n !=0){
    r=m%n;
    m=n;
    n=r;
  }
  return m;
}
```

somehow longgcd.cpp can't compile. i get an error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.3.2/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [longgcd] Error 1
```

somehow I have difficulty running this program and making it work, i can't see whats wrong with it. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: have you tried placing both functions in the same file and compile it?

Comment: A few points to make your code better (aside the actual showstoppers mentioned in the comments): 1) You might want to consider testing if `argv` is actually at least `3` before accessing the arguments. 2)Generally In c++ it is considered good practice to declare variables at the point they are initialized, instead of at the beginning of the function. This makes the code more tense and can even be more performance-efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show the line you used to compile? It sounds like you tried to compile `longgcd.cpp` independently as an executable, and since that file doesn't have `main`, the linker correctly complained that it couldn't find `main`.

The simplest solution is to compile both files together

```
g++ $FLAGS longgcd.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: Actually that isn't the solution. Note the `#include "longgcd.cpp"` in main.cpp. That might be a bad idea, but the way it stands `longgcd.cpp` doesn't actually need to be compiled seperately.

Comment: @Grizzly: I didn't notice that. But it still sounds like the OP tried to compile longgcd.cpp independently.

Comment: I'm not disputing that part of the answer. I only wanted to mention that to be correct your answer would either mention removing that include, or not mention `longgcd.cpp` in the compiler call.

Answer (score 1):

You should be compiling the source file that contains the `main()` function.

Note that `#include`ing cpp's is generally discouraged. You can put the declaration for `gcd` in a header file and include this file from both the implementation cpp containing the code for it and the main file that calls it. In this case you will need to specify *both* cpp files to the compiler command line because they're both needed to assemble the final program. Even with this complication this way is much better than including cpps.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that `main` should be in your .cpp file, and not your header.

Another is that you normally `#include` a header (.h or .hpp) into a .cpp file and not the other way around.

Also please get a decent C++ book to read.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include `longgcd.cpp`.  You should almost never include a `.cpp` (unless you really, really, know what is going down)

You should specify all the `cpp`s to the compiler.  E.g: `g++ main.cpp longgcd.cpp`

Also move the `long gcd(long m, long n);` line above your main function.